# Something similar to Guava's LoadingCache, but bidirectional?

Tags: java, caching, guava

I'm working with an account system that allows users to change their display names. To accomplish this, each user has a [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html). At various points in my program, I may have a UUID and want its current display name, or I may have a current display name and I'd like to look up the UUID. Looking it up involves either a database call or http request, so I'd like to cache results in memory. I'm familiar with [Guava's LoadingCache](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/cache/LoadingCache.html), but it seems like I'd have to create two caches (names -> UUIDs and UUIDs -> names) in order to accomplish this. [This seems bug-prone, similar to how a BiMap is better than two synchronous maps](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#bimap) Is there something similar to a bidirectional LoadingCache out there?

Comment: Can two users have the same display name? If so, then your reverse lookup must handle that somehow and it is not one-to-one. You'll probably want to keep the id hidden with the display name instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case, I wouldn't necessarily worry about a pair of caches being bug prone: you don't have to keep the two directions in sync, and if you fail to do so there's no real failures.  UUIDs and their relationships to users aren't going to change.

Keeping a bidirectional cache correctly synchronized is difficult, but for this case it seems like overkill.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess my main concern is a situation like querying UUID -> name, and soon after asking for that same name's UUID. I don't want to have to go looking up information that I already have (albeit backwards, in another cache)

Comment: That race condition is somewhat unavoidable, but you can reduce it by doing e.g. `putIfAbsent` in the reverse cache.  You're going to have races, and they're going to result in maybe more queries than you'd like, but they'll be benign races, and anything better would be super complicated if it was possible at all.